# SQL - using the Min field to achieve desired result

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Wondering the best SQL to handle below situation:  Client only wants to see invoices that have been declined.  I started with only show me when STATUS_ID = 2, but then realized that it was paid as it was resubmitted and accepted so that didn't work.  What is the best way to handle 2 records like below where I don't want the SQL to return any records if manifest + order code have a 1.  Would you do a Min on Status ID or something of that nature?

VENDOR NAME manifest    ORDER_CODE          STATUS_ID
VENDOR 12345    BHGSDKJF1234    RU07                   2 (invoice decline)
VENDOR 12345    BHGSDKJF1234    RU07                   1 (paid)

Answer (score 0):

This trick can be work for you in this case, but it's not solve the general case (what happens if the STATUS_ID for paid is 3, and all possible values are 0-5?)

you can use in general SWICH-CASE clause, that gives you some 1 (true) if the client has STATUS_ID = 1, and 0 otherwise. Then, pick the MAX() for each invoice.

You can also consider another design that might work for you:
Add time\time-stamp column (Maybe, for your purpose, you can use SYSDATE time for insertion time of the record to db).
After you have a time column, you probably can choose the columns with the last time STATUS_ID for each invoice (get the STATUS_ID in the row with the max time).